# Volume above cone $z = a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and inside sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume of the region: $$\iiint(x^2+y^2+z^2)dV $$ where $R$ is the region above the cone $z = a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Just find the intersection point. Write $x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta,$ $y=\rho \sin\phi \sin\theta$, and $z=\rho \cos \phi$. At the place of intersection (see a picture), $\rho= b$. Moreover, by symmetry, we can find the angle $\phi$ for any $\theta$.

We have $z^2=a^2(x^2+y^2)$ so plugging this into the second one, we have
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+a^2(x^2+y^2)=b^2\implies x^2+y^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}.
\end{align}
On the cone, this means $z=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} = b\cos\phi$. Therefore,
$$
\phi=\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}):=\alpha.
$$
Using $dV=\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho d\phi d\theta$the setup in spherical coordinates is then
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\alpha\int_0^b \rho^4\sin\phi\, d\rho d\phi d\theta
$$
The angle $\alpha$ looks ugly, but when you plug it in, it ends up inverting with the cosine function.

Comment: Can you explain the $x^2+y^2 = b^2/a^2+1$ and the  alpha part again?

Comment: If you draw a picture, the first equation ( that you're referring to) shows the circle where the cone and sphere intersect.

Comment: Ok. I actually understand that equation now but still confused about alpha.

Comment: $\alpha$ is just what I called the inverse cosine expression.

Comment: Oh ok. But why did ab/sqrt(a^2+1) become b cos phi. Is that just an identity?

Comment: Because from $x^2+y^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}$, you plug that into the cone and get $z=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=a\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2+1}}$. But, at this same point on the sphere, $z=b \cos\phi$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: So is the answer:
$2πb^5/5(1−\sqrt{a/1+a^2})$

Comment: @zugzug, Why did you write $ \rho^4 \sin{\phi}$ instead of $\rho^2 \sin{\phi}$ in your integral?

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates, the bottom and top surfaces are $z=ar$ and $z=\sqrt{b^2-r^2}$, respectively. Then, the enclosed volume is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R \left(\sqrt{b^2-r^2}-ar\right) rdrd\theta
= \frac{2\pi b^3}3\left(1-\frac a{\sqrt{1+a^2}} \right)$$

where the radial upper limit is the intersection of the two curves, i.e. $R=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$.

Comment: So what would the final answer be? Is it what I got?

Comment: @FreshDough - The final answer is $\frac{2\pi b^3}3\left(1-\frac a{\sqrt{1+a^2}} \right)$. Yours is incorrect. For instance, if $a=0$, the volume should be  a half sphere $\frac {2\pi}3b^3$

Comment: I don't think yours is correct either. What if a =2 and b=sqrt 5. Shouldn't the answer then be 20pi/3

Comment: @FreshDough - why $20\pi/3$?

Comment: Thats what I calculated. Not sure

Comment: @FreshDough - pretty sure it is incorrect

Comment: @FreshDough - another special case you could check is $a=b=1$

Comment: I think you are missing the extra r^2+z^2 term so I think the answer should be 
$2πb^5/5(1−\sqrt{a/1+a^2})$

Comment: @Quanto, Would you show me the steps in your computation of your integral in cylindrical coordinates because my hp 50g emulator on pc also don't give your answer even after simplification?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod - $$\int_0^R \left(\sqrt{b^2-r^2}-ar\right) rdr= -\frac13[a r^3 + (b^2-r^2)^{3/2}]\bigg|_0^{\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}}
$$